# Question about RFID reader sensitivity

Tags: rfid

I have read that in RFID systems, the range is almost always dependent on the tags sensitivity to pick up the signal, not the readers. But this information is related to UHF RFID systems, and I would like to ask if it's the same in low frequency systems?

I'm asking this, because I'm doing a COMSOL Multiphysics simulation on determening the read range of a tag in a certain environment, and I would like to know, that can I make the evaluation of the range based only on how far the tag still can receive a strong enough signal to activate itself and send the signal back?

Comment: It's often the case that the tag gets enough power from the magnetic field but is too far away to make an effective modulation to the field that the reader can adequately recognize. It's a tricky one to be definite about without having a second passive reader able to make a close up scrutinization of the field close to the tag.

Comment: @Andyaka Okey, so it's basically impossible to make any evaluation of the range just by simulating the magnetic fields? Unfortunately due to the corona situation I wont' be able to do any real world testing because the campus is closed and I don't have the equipment needed.

Comment: Probably not because so much depends on the reader's ability to discern small shifts in modulation on its own carrier against a background of noise.